# Issue with getting colors in a Blender imported mesh to be shown using Three.js

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, blender

I am trying to display glued cubes, imported from blender, using Three.js.

I am using latest Version of  Three.js and Blender 2.78a.

I started by making my cube object;just like this: 
https://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2015/07/27/importing-blender-modelized-mesh-in-threejs.html
But I have different/more glued cubes.

[image]

I  created above 3d object in Blender, Then exported the mesh using the Three.js .js exporter.

Here is the **marmelab.json** file.

```
{
    "metadata":{
        "generator":"io_three",
        "faces":6,
        "type":"Geometry",
        "version":3,
        "materials":1,
        "normals":6,
        "vertices":24,
        "uvs":1
    },
    "faces":[43,8,10,12,14,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,43,16,18,20,22,0,3,0,1,2,1,1,1,1,43,9,15,19,17,0,3,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,43,1,13,21,5,0,3,0,1,2,3,3,3,3,43,3,11,23,7,0,3,0,1,2,4,4,4,4,43,2,0,4,6,0,3,0,1,2,5,5,5,5],
    "materials":[{
        "DbgIndex":0,
        "blending":"NormalBlending",
        "opacity":1,
        "depthWrite":true,
        "visible":true,
        "transparent":false,
        "colorEmissive":[0,0,0],
        "colorDiffuse":[0.8,0.432941,0],
        "wireframe":false,
        "DbgName":"01 - Default",
        "specularCoef":11,
        "colorSpecular":[0.18,0.18,0.18],
        "DbgColor":15658734,
        "depthTest":true,
        "shading":"phong"
    }],
    "normals":[0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,1,-0,1,0,-0,0,-1,-0,-1,0,-0],
    "name":"Untitled.001Geometry.1",
    "vertices":[-0.307576,-0,-0.433258,-0.002776,-0,-0.433258,-0.307576,-0,-0.738058,-0.002776,-0,-0.738058,-0.307576,0.3048,-0.433258,-0.002776,0.3048,-0.433258,-0.307576,0.3048,-0.738058,-0.002776,0.3048,-0.738058,-0.307576,-0,-0.433258,-0.307576,-0,-0.433258,-0.307576,-0,-0.738058,-0.307576,-0,-0.738058,-0.002776,-0,-0.738058,-0.002776,-0,-0.738058,-0.002776,-0,-0.433258,-0.002776,-0,-0.433258,-0.307576,0.3048,-0.433258,-0.307576,0.3048,-0.433258,-0.002776,0.3048,-0.433258,-0.002776,0.3048,-0.433258,-0.002776,0.3048,-0.738058,-0.002776,0.3048,-0.738058,-0.307576,0.3048,-0.738058,-0.307576,0.3048,-0.738058],
    "uvs":[[1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0]]
}
```

javascript to load the mesh and display

```
var scene, camera, renderer;

var WIDTH  = window.innerWidth;
var HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

var SPEED = 0.01;

function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    initMesh();
    initCamera();
    initLights();
    initRenderer();

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function initCamera() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 1, 10);
    camera.position.set(0, 3.5, 5);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
}


function initRenderer() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

function initLights() {
    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
    scene.add(light);
}

var mesh = null;
function initMesh() {
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load('./marmelab.json', function(geometry, materials) {
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
        mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = 0.75;
        mesh.translation = THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
        scene.add(mesh);
    });
}

function rotateMesh() {
    if (!mesh) {
        return;
    }

    mesh.rotation.x -= SPEED * 2;
    mesh.rotation.y -= SPEED;
    mesh.rotation.z -= SPEED * 3;
}

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    rotateMesh();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
render();
```

However in Browser the shape is rtained ; but the color is white.

What am I missing here?

Thank you so much in advance.

[image]

Comment: What revision of Three.js do you use?

Comment: @prisoner849,  I am using the latest one r82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

I updated the Plunker with the latest version of `three.js` and it now works with your unedited json above - http://plnkr.co/edit/RwkgzrvfqzYlWtShhpjt?p=preview

Also successfully tested with my own, more complicated, model - http://plnkr.co/edit/SWXv1GyKIGryORiNYlgx?p=preview

The problem is caused by using an older version of `three.js`.  I originally tested using the version provided by the website you linked to. I suspect you might have done the same given the result.

Somewhere around revision 70 they changed the exporter to no longer export the `colorAmbient` property, and that older version of `Three.js` required it.

Comment: @K Scandrett, I put everywhere the colorAmbient attribute but it doen't work for more than one cube. For one cube which you have done , it works perfectly fine. setting values for the material to 'lambert' didn't help. Color ambient still doesnt appear. What source to follow to properly export that json?

Comment: I downloaded the latest version of Blender last night to find the answers for you, but everytime I start it it crashes Windows. I'll see if I can resolve that problem tomorrow and get back to you

Comment: Thank you so much. Version of three.js is r71 to be precise. :)